# QML ui-toolkit on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the QML toolkit on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235440/how-do-i-install-the-qml-toolkit-on-12-04)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I prefer to keep on an LTS distribution.  I tried to install the QML ui-toolkit and the ppa doesn't work on my current install of Ubuntu. Will I be able to install it? Will you port the repository?

I don't think I will update since I work with my computer and I prefer to stick to an LTS.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you added which PPA doesn't work.

Comment: @Timo: santi likely refers to the ui-toolkit PPA. It is obvious when you reminds the QML toolkit installation instructions : http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit .

Comment: @air-dex is right. I was talking about this ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1. I saw the video about Ubuntu mobile and I tried to install it on Ubuntu 12.04.